Astro + i18next. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') LanguageSelector.astro
I'm trying to install i18next in my astro project, but I'm facing an issue with the new i18next version package. I use this reference. And then I updated dependencies
  "dependencies": {
    "astro": "^4.11.3",
    "astro-i18next": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "i18next": "^23.11.5"
  }

I got this error:

TypeError An error occurred. Cannot read properties of undefined
(reading 'map') components/LanguageSelector.astro:26:19

node_modules/astro-i18next/src/components/LanguageSelector.astro
---
import i18next from "i18next";
import { localizePath } from "../..";
import localeEmoji from "locale-emoji";
import ISO6991 from "iso-639-1";

interface languageMapping {
  [localeCode: string]: string;
}

export interface Props extends astroHTML.JSX.SelectHTMLAttributes {
  showFlag?: boolean;
  languageMapping?: languageMapping;
}

const supportedLanguages = i18next.languages;
const currentLanguage = i18next.language;

const { pathname } = Astro.url;

const { showFlag = false, languageMapping, ...attributes } = Astro.props;
---

<select onchange="location = this.value;" {...attributes}>
  {
    supportedLanguages.map((supportedLanguage: string) => {
      let value = localizePath(pathname, supportedLanguage);
      const flag = showFlag ? localeEmoji(supportedLanguage) + " " : "";

      let nativeName = "";
      if (
        languageMapping &&
        languageMapping.hasOwnProperty(supportedLanguage)
      ) {
        nativeName = languageMapping[supportedLanguage];
      } else {
        nativeName = ISO6991.getNativeName(supportedLanguage);
      }

      const label = flag + nativeName;

      return (
        <option value={value} selected={supportedLanguage === currentLanguage}>
          {label}
        </option>
      );
    })
  }
</select>

All configs are the same as in the reference. And I wouldn't want to downgrade the package.

The error message points to line 26, so apparently supportedLanguages is undefined and therefore supportedLanguages.map doesn't work (hence "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"). not sure why though

Did you try deleting node_modules/ and package-lock.json?

I installed a fresh version of Astro and followed the instructions at https://github.com/yassinedoghri/astro-i18next/tree/beta. My working repo is here: https://github.com/fullstackdev42/astro-i18next-1.0.0-beta.21

I noticed the repo you linked to is to a commit. The configs in there are not the same as in my repo. Not sure if it matters either but did you do a npx astro-i18next generate?

@Russell thank you! All my problem was in package-lock.json. I forgot delete it, I deleted only node_modules/. I'm a fool

I downgraded only i18next to version ^22.4.10 and this did not affect other dependencies. This solved the error, but this bug is still there on ^23.11.5 (the latest one at the moment)
upd. thank you @Russell! I forgot delete package-lock.json. I deleted only node_modules/.
